# Expected number of questions when the student knows 50 out of 250 questions and the teacher selects 25

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A teacher has 250 sample test questions and he selects 25 of which to put on the test. Johnny only practices 50 out of the 250 questions.

a) What's the expected number of questions that appear on the exam that Johnny have practiced on?

My answer:
I'm quite confused so I don't think it's the right answer. I know that the expected value is just
$$\sum_{k=1}^{25} \left[kp(k)\right]$$

However, I'm not sure what $p(k)$ is. I think it's $$ \frac{25}{250} \frac{50}{250}  = 0.02 $$ which would make $E(X) = 6.5$

b) What's the probability that Johnny hasn't practiced any of the exam questions?

My answer:
Here I tried using the hypergeometric distribution and set N = 250, r = 25, n = 50, and x = 0. Obviously assuming here that if Johnny sees a question he's practiced he'll be able to solve it.
This means the final answer will be
$$\frac {{50 \choose 0}{225 \choose 50}} {{250 \choose 50}}$$
which is
$$\frac {{225 \choose 50}} {{250 \choose 50}}$$

Are those answers correct? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The answer to the second part is correct.  The answer to the first part?  Not so much.  A hint for the first part: linearity of expectation.  $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$.  What is the probability that the first question appearing on the text was in fact one that our student studied?  What is the probability the second question appearing on the test was in fact one that our student studied?  Dependence of these two events is completely irrelevant.  Make sure you understand why.

Comment: Your approach for #1 is reasonable, however the $p(k)$ you are talking about trying to find is quite complicated, more complicated than a beginning student is expected to be able to find on their own.  Even worse... even assuming you could find an appropriate expression for $p(k)$, simplifying the sum is hardly an easy task.  The approach with linearity of expectation on the other hand is trivial, should be intuitive, and could have been correctly guessed.

Comment: @JMoravitz Personally, I initially regarded the fact that Linearity of Expectation does not require independent events to be counter intuitive.  It wasn't until I saw the proof, in the brillant.org link in my answer, that I was forced to accept this conclusion.  One might suppose that **meta-cheating** might have suggested this result.  That is, if the expected value computation required arduous consideration of dependent events, then one would have to wonder why the problem composer posed the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz I suspect that what is really happening is that the problem composer intended that the student has already been exposed to the Linearity of Expectation result, as part of training.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now after looking at the brilliant article and the answers. Since Linearity of Expectation doesn't require the events themsevles to be independent, $(1/5)(25)$ is equal to adding up all the individual expected values right?

Comment: Yes, that it's it exactly.  Also, there is the hidden **meta-cheating** issue.  Problem composers generally have some educational value in mind, and reasonable plan of attack in mind, when they pose a question.  Typically, when you are assigned a problem, it is merely an application of the training that the problem composer has supposedly recently given you.  I would expect this to apply to any math courses, below the graduate level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the expected number of questions that appear on the exam that Johnny have practiced on?

Johnny practices on $50$ out of $250$ questions.  This implies that at random, any question has a $(1/5)$th probability of being a question that Johnny has practiced on.

[Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) does **not** require that the events be independent.

Consider the following $2$ events:

- $E_1$ : Johnny practiced on the 1st question chosen by the teacher.
- $E_2$ : Johnny practiced on the 2nd question chosen by the teacher.

When computing the expected number of the questions, out of the $(25)$ chosen by the teacher, that Johnny will have practiced on, it is **irrelevant** (for example) that events $E_1$ and $E_2$ above are not independent events.

So, the expected number of questions, out of the $(25)$ questions chosen by the teacher, that Johnny will have practiced on is

$$(1/5) \times 25 = 5.$$

---

> What's the probability that Johnny hasn't practiced any of the exam questions?

The probability may be expressed as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

$N$ will denote the number of ways of selecting $25$ questions from the $200$ that Johnny did not practice on.

$D$ will denote the number of ways of selecting $25$ questions from any of the $250$ questions.

So, the probability is

$$\frac{\binom{200}{25}}{\binom{250}{25}}.$$

**Edit**
See the comment of JMoravitz, following my answer.  In fact, I did think that the OP's (i.e. original poster's) answer of

$$\frac{\binom{225}{50}}{\binom{250}{50}}$$

was automatically wrong because it involved Combinations different from mine.  It never occurred to me that the $2$ answers are equivalent.

---

For what it's worth, my approach was to focus on the $25$ questions selected, reasoning that they had to be part of the $200$ questions that Johnny did not practice on.

The OP took the valid (but opposite) viewpoint.  He reasoned that the $50$ questions that Johnny did practice on had to be contained in the $225$ questions that were **not** selected.

Comment: To emphasize, $\dfrac{\binom{200}{25}}{\binom{250}{25}} = \dfrac{\binom{225}{50}}{\binom{250}{50}}$.  At a glance, one might have thought you were saying the OP's answer to part 2 was wrong when it is not.  Both yours and OP's answers are correct, just appearing in a different form.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are absolutely right.  That is what I was saying.  I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JMoravitz Both equal $\frac{250!}{175!50!25!}$ when multiplied through.

Comment: @JMP I was the one who didn't realize that until JMoravitz pointed it out.